# Troubleshooting empty params[] hash since Rails3 Upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a named route that tests properly in the console and shows the :url_title which should be included in params[], yet params[] is always empty.

The question is, why is params[] empty? My expectation is it should have params[:url_title].

I also removed this route and used the default resource and params[] is still empty.

I've been checking params by using logger.

My app is an upgrade from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.0.3.

Here's a code summary of what's going on.

```
# this is my route
match 'papers/:url_title' => 'papers#show', :as => :permalinkpaper

# this is link_to and the generated url being called
<%= link_to paper.title, paper_path(paper.url_title) %>
http://localhost:3000/papers/great-passion

# which properly matches to this controller#action for papers#show 
def show
    @paper = Paper.where(:url_title => params[:url_title]).first()
    PaperHistory.add( current_user, @paper.id )

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @paper }
      format.json { render :json => @paper }
      format.mobile # { render :layout => false }
    end
  end

# which generals this error because the Paper looking returns noting because the params[:url_title] is nil
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

# the log stack trace
Started GET "/papers/great-passion" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jan 24 23:04:04 -0600 2011
  Processing by PapersController#show as HTML

  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Paper Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `papers`.* FROM `papers` WHERE (`papers`.`url_title` IS NULL) ORDER BY title LIMIT 1
Completed   in 119ms

RuntimeError (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
  app/controllers/papers_controller.rb:43:in `show'



# I've validated the route in the console and it seems to know :url_title is the proper value
>> r = ActionController::Routing::Routes
>> r.recognize_path "/papers/great-passion"
=> {:action=>"show", :url_title=>"great-passion", :controller=>"papers"}
```

UPDATE: I have found that params[] are NOT empty when values are in the URL, such as when performing a search.

http://localhost:3000/papers?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=passion

This successfully produces

```
Started GET "/papers?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=passion" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jan 25 00:20:07 -0600 2011
  Processing by PapersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "keywords"=>"passion"}
params: utf8✓keywordspassion
```

Comment: Can you post your form's code?

Comment: It's a link actually. <%= link_to paper.title, paper_path(paper.url_title) %>

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the code you posted.  Prior to the `match` line you posted, is there anything else regarding papers in routes.rb?

Comment: Yes, I have several routes papers. I just realized a few minutes ago that routes appear to parse from the bottom up now, whereas they used to go top down in Rails 2...unless I'm misremembering in my delirium. I'll comment out all other refs to paper in the routes and see where that gets me.

Comment: Cleansed the routes with the exception of the one that handles this and it had no impact. params[] still nil.

Comment: Not even `resources :papers`?

Comment: Right, I removed all :papers routes leaving just my route above. It seems to be routing properly other than dropping the params. I'm beginning to think I need to start this upgrade over from scratch.

Comment: Hm.  I was thinking that if `resources :papers` were still in there, the default route for 'show' would apply, which takes `:id` as the parameter.  But since you took that out...  Have you tried altering the route for a test, as in '/papers/test/:url_title'?  Or taken the last match out as well to see if the exception changes?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried tweaking the route, and even tried the resource route to get :id coming thru. Nothing. Only time I get anything in params[] is via querystring. Leads me to believe I borked something in the upgrade. I get this empty params[] on other routes as well, so it's not just this one.

Comment: I have one more idea: Did you include the `csrf_meta_tag` in your layouts?  XSS protection might screw up parameters, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. All are welcome! I was not including csrf_meta_tag. I just added it and it makes no difference. Because it's not a form post, I'm not sure it would. Nothing in the url is being brought through to the params hash.

Comment: OK, FOUND THE PROBLEM/SOLUTION. I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all for the help. I was able to disassemble my app piece by piece and finally get params[] to show up.

The culprit was the **open_id_authentication** plugin.

I had some plugins in the vendors directory, so I removed them all and after hurdling a few resulting errors (b/c the plugins were now missing) everything worked. I systematically replaced plugins, and when I got to open_id_authentication found that the params[] again disappeared.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this.  I had the exact same problem.  Did you find any updated openid code to replace that plugin with?

Comment: No, I decided to remove openid. I was about the only person that registered with it. The other 1000+ registrations bypassed it and just entered user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different solution for this problem that I'll post here just in case somebody runs into the same issue. I was working on a password reset part of the site and tried various things such as putting the URL in manually, specifying the controller and action, using a bare (minimal) form and such, but all of it failed. The error given was the e-mail parameter was blank.

A look into the Exceptional logs showed that not just the e-mail parameter was blank, but even the UTF-8 check mark was missing. The only things in the params hash were the controller and action. Reloading the page also didn't turn up the usual spiel about re-submitting information.

It turns out the problem was in **SSL**. The page was trying to use SSL but didn't have permission and it was somehow silently killing the form. Hope that helps somebody.